# Prevent site from being viewed as IP

Tags: php, apache

If my website is an A record of 0.0.0.0 for my website example.com, how could I prevent visitors from going to 0.0.0.0? Is there a setting in Apache or PHP where I can block people from viewing the website from location that are not example.com?

Is there a $_SERVER variable I could use to get this information? I have read the PHP docs on server variables and I have seen nothing about getting the "host".

Thank you.

Comment: https://serverfault.com/q/114931

Comment: You mean you don't want people to access the site via its IP address? Why is that a problem?

Comment: I self host and its a bit of a security concern.

Comment: How is it a security concern exactly? An IP address identifies the host. It is always public (at least within a LAN, if not on the internet). A hostname configured in DNS is only a way of making a more human-friendly way of finding the machine, but it just points to the IP. Again, that info is public by necessity. What vulnerability do you think is caused by accessing your server via its IP address? I can't think what you are concerned about specifically.

Comment: I suppose it isn't a real concern but I would rather not have people know by approximate location by using a search engine like [Shodan](https://shodan.io) to get the IP of my site. I use Cloudflare to mask my site's IP.

Comment: Ultimately if you want to be able to connect to your site then the IP address must be discoverable or knowable at some point. That's how IP networks work. A hostname is just a convenient alias for it. Functionally it doesn't make any difference.

Comment: Anyway if your concern is to stop people discovering your IP address then I can say for certain that PHP can't help you with that. If someone manages to execute a PHP script on your server then they have definitely found your IP address (or your hostname, as I said it doesn't actually matter which one is used, since they both lead to the same place).

Comment: If you give them the name of the site example.com then it's just a DNS lookup to get the IP. https://www.whatismyip.com/dns-lookup/

Comment: But if you're using a service like cloudflare to act as an edge server and mask the true IP then there shouldn't really be anything to worry about anyway, because your real IP won't ever be public. Instead your domain name points to a cloudflare IP.

Comment: If you use Cloudflare, that returns the IP of a Cloudflare datacenter.

Comment: There are always IP lookup services, but I suppose you do have a point.